# ¿Por qué si ejecuto este código me salta el siguiente error: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:?

Tags: python

Al ejecutar la actividad 1 t 2 me funciona, pero poniendo el mismo nodo en la actividad 3 no me funciona. El objetivo de la actividad 3 es crear una funcion recursiva que me imprima las lineas de cada fichero de un directorio y que a su vez, luego me imprima el total de lineas que tenia el directorio. La actividad 1 hace un ejemplo de como hacer la exploracion y la 2 es la que cuenta las lines. Esas dos funcionan a la perfeccion pero tenemos problemas con la 3.

```
import pathlib

# actividad 1

def explorar(fs_node):
    for entry in fs_node.iterdir():
        print(entry)
        if entry.is_dir():
            explorar(entry)
                
# actividad 2
def contar_lineas(fs_node, word):
    with fs_node.open() as f:
        s=0
        for line in f:
            if word in line.lower().split():
                s+=1
        return s
    

# actividad 3

def explorar_contar(fs_node, word,t=0):
    for entry in fs_node.iterdir():
        if entry.is_file(): 
            lineas = contar_lineas(fs_node, word)
            t+=lineas
            print(f"{lineas:4d} " , fs_node)
        elif entry.is_dir(): 
            explorar_contar(entry, word)
            print(f"{t:4d} " , entry)
    print(f"{t:4d} " , fs_node)
            


            

# programa principal (no cambiéis nada en esta parte)
def main():
    opcion = ""
    while opcion not in ('1','2','3'):
        opcion = input('Elige actividad:\n 1) Recorrido recursivo\n'+
                       ' 2) Contar lineas\n 3) Recorrido recursivo '+
                       'contando lineas\nOpcion: ')
        if opcion not in ('1','2','3'):
            print('Opcion incorrecta')

    ruta = input("Nombre del fichero o carpeta (enter para 'GCD'): ")
    if ruta == '':
        ruta = 'GCD'
    fs_node = pathlib.Path(ruta)
    
    if not fs_node.exists():
        print(f"Error: no se encuentra el fichero o carpeta '{fs_node}'")
        return
    
    elif opcion == '1':
        if not fs_node.is_dir():
            print(f"Error: {fs_node} no es un directorio")
            return
        explorar(fs_node)
    else:
        word = input('Palabra a buscar: ').lower()
        if opcion == '2':
            if not fs_node.is_file():
                print(f"Error: {fs_node} no es un fichero")
                return
            cuenta = contar_lineas(fs_node, word)
            print(f'Hay {cuenta} lineas con la palabra {word}')
        else:
            explorar_contar(fs_node, word)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece ser un typo, en `lineas = contar_lineas(fs_node, word)`. Estás diciendo a la función que cuente las líneas de un "archivo" que en realidad es un directorio, por eso sale el mensaje de "*permission denied*". Para corregirlo hay que cambiar `fs_node` por `entry`:

```py
def explorar_contar(fs_node, word,t=0):
    for entry in fs_node.iterdir():
        if entry.is_file(): 
            lineas = contar_lineas(entry, word) # <-- Aqui estaba el error
            t += lineas
            print(f"{lineas:4d} " , entry) 
        elif entry.is_dir(): 
            explorar_contar(entry, word)
            # print(f"{t:4d} " , entry) # <-- No es necesario
    print(f"{t:4d} " , fs_node)
```

Comment: Primero de todo mil gracias por tu ayuda, sinceramente es mi primera vez utilizando esta plataforma y no esperaba tu respuesta. Por otra parte, ¿que le faltaria añadir al codigo para que cuando imprimiera los directorios, tambien tuviera en cuenta el total? Me lia el hecho de que la funcion no hace ningun return por lo que no se sumar por recursividad. Te comparto respuesta